# How to login to a spring security login form using cURL?

Tags: java, curl, spring-security

I am working on a springMVC project in which the user authentication is based on spring security.

the idea is to have a mobile (android) application to be able to send some sort of data to backend.

So before get my hand dirty into android developing I decided to mock the situation of login form using cURL.

the login form in our site is as following :

```
http://localhost:8080/app/user/login
```

and I use following command :

```
curl -F 'username=admin&password=admin' http://localhost:8080/app/user/login
```

but yet I will get login page in other words I am not able to pass user authentication based on a mock up situation.

just to note : for every request the spring secure will create a randomize token something similar to  :

> 8863F732ADDE24CD167F4EF502A4333D

how should I pass login form based on spring security using mock situation (either `cURL` or `HTTPClient`)

Comment: permission denied or from curl the same login form.

Comment: Could you show relevant spring-security configuration?

Comment: Consider replacing the first occurrence of "login" with "log in" in the title.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `cURL` like this:

```
 curl -d j_username=admin -d j_password=admin -L http://localhost:8080/app/j_spring_security_check
```

#### CSRF

If you get something like `Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?` that means that CSRF token protection is enabled. To test it with cURL you need a cookie and a CSRF token itself.

The following command will write all cookies to a file named `cookie` and print out the CSRF token. Spring Security default token parameter name is `_csrf`, if you've changed it then you need to change `grep csrf` also.

```
curl --cookie-jar cookie -L http://localhost:8080/app/j_spring_security_check  | grep csrf
```

Then you can execute next command which will pass all cookies from file. Don't forget to replace `|your_token_value|` with an actual value which is printed out by the previous command (and `_csrf` parameter name if you've changed it).

```
curl --cookie cookie -d "j_username=admin&j_password=admin&_csrf=|your_token_value|" -L http://localhost:8080/app/j_spring_security_check
```

#### From Spring Security 3.x to 4.x

Note that in Spring Security 4.x default value for `login-processing-url` changed from `/j_spring_security_check` to POST `/login`, default value for `username-parameter` changed from `j_username` to `username` and default value for `password-parameter` changed from `j_password` to `password`. If an application explicitly provides these attributes, no action is required for the migration.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I do get `Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?` when I try this (Spring Boot 1.3.1). I know I can disable CSRF, but I was wondering how to do it when it is enabled?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Updated my answer with info how to use curl when spring-security csrf is enabled.

Comment: Does this work when I have specified an external SSO page to login with a CAS server? I keep getting redirected to the login page there and it does not login.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the most voted answer, I wrote the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

curl --cookie-jar cookie -L http://localhost:PORT/secureDomain/secureURL

TOKEN=$( cat cookie | grep 'XSRF' | cut -f7 )

curl --cookie cookie -u admin:admin -d "_csrf=$TOKEN" -L http://localhost:PORT/secureDomain/secureURL
```

Works for Spring Security 4.

Answer (score 3):

You should configure spring to support basic authentication. Then add to your request the following header:

- name: `Authorization`
- value: `base64(username:password)`

That means that user name and password should be cocatenated into one string with `:` as separator and then transformed using `BASE64` transformation.

Comment: Actually I don't want to add basic Auth to current config (due to security concerns) but I think there should be a way to mock up the web form.

Comment: Could you please expand by adding some command line examples?

Answer (score 2):

If CSRF is enabled, you need to capture the token value from the output of every request, in order to use it in the next one.

```
BASEURL="http://localhost:8080/hac"
csrf=$(curl --silent --cookie-jar cookies.txt -L "$BASEURL/login.jsp" | egrep -o -m1 "[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12}")
csrf=$(curl --silent --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar cookies.txt -L "$BASEURL/j_spring_security_check" --data "j_username=$USERNAME&j_password=$PASSWORD&_csrf=$csrf" | egrep -o -m1 "[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12}" )
```

You can chain more commands in this manner, updating the value of `$csrf` every time.

This worked on Spring security 3.

Answer (score 1):

This script worked for me with Spring Boot 2.1.6 and Spring Security 5.1.5:

```
# Obtain the CSRF token _plus_ the JSESSIONID cookie to go along with it.
export CSRF_TOKEN=$(curl -s -c cookies.txt -L http://localhost:8080/login | \
  grep -Eo "name=\"_csrf\" value=\"[0-9a-z-]+\"" | cut -d= -f3 | tr -d '"')

echo "Found csrf token: $CSRF_TOKEN"

# Login with the username and password, reading from (-b) and updating (-c) the cookie jar file.
curl -s -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt -X POST \
     -F "username=admin" -F "password=password" -F "_csrf=$CSRF_TOKEN" http://localhost:8080/login

SESSION_ID=$(grep "JSESSIONID" cookies.txt | cut -f 7)
echo "Got session token: $SESSION_ID"

# Finally, execute authorized API action
curl -sL -b cookies.txt "http://localhost:8080/authorized/url"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough for me to use just -d options. Our web application is hosted by Tomcat, located in webapps/ROOT folder and have the following configuration:

```
<form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
    authentication-success-handler-ref="appAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    authentication-failure-handler-ref="appAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    username-parameter="j_username" 
    password-parameter="j_password" 
    login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>

<csrf disabled="true"/>

<headers>
    <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
</headers>
```

The following works to send POST request to our web application (assuming Tomcat is listening on port 8080):

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -c cookies.txt -H "Origin: http://localhost:8080/" -d "j_username=USERNAME&j_password=PASSWORD" -X POST http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check
curl -i -d @JSON_FILE -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Origin: http://localhost:8080/" -b cookies.txt -X POST http://localhost:8080/URL
```

Replace USERNAME, PASSWORD, JSON_FILE and URL with your own.