# How to login via form post with CURL (spring security app)

Tags: curl, spring-security

No command has worked yet and all i ever get returned is the html form. What command should I be using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13048954/1700321

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to login to Spring security app:

```
curl -i -X POST -d j_username=user -d j_password=pass http://localhost:8080/static/j_spring_security_check
```

Note: it works only if the [CSRF](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html) is disabled.