# How to login to a Spring login form using node-fetch

Tags: node.js, typescript, spring, node-fetch

I have access to a Spring application via a username and password from my browser and I want to login from a NodeJS application.

I followed the post ([How to login to a spring security login form using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048954/how-to-login-to-a-spring-security-login-form-using-curl)), which allowed me to successfully use cURL or Postman. But, I'm encountering issues when attempting to implement this in NodeJS. I've also attempted to use a cookieJar to automate the process of managing cookies, but I'm still experiencing difficulties.

Basically I tried to:

- Get CSRF and SESSIONID tokens by pinging the login page
- Then I connect using these tokens and giving my identifiers
- Here the redirects are happening and supposed to give me a new SESSIONID and a new CSRF token. I note that with my script I received a second 'Set-cookie' which did not happen when I log in from the browser.
- I tried to use them to get the API but I can't fetch the data.

Here's the code I've drafted. Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong ?

```
const extractTokens = (r: any): [string, string] => {
  const csrf = r.headers.get('x-csrf-token')!
  const cookie = r.headers.get('set-cookie')?.split(';')[0]
  return [csrf, cookie]
}

const ping = async () => {
  return fetch('https://lap.drc.ngo/login/root', {
    keepalive: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'GET',
  })
}

const login = async ([csrf, session]: [string, string]) => {
  return await fetch('https://lap.drc.ngo/j_spring_security_check', {
    keepalive: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Cookie': session,
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(`email:password`)
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({_csrf: csrf,})
  })
}

const getData = async ([csrf, session]: [string, string]) => {
  return fetch('https://lap.drc.ngo/admin/msd/get-list-data', {
    keepalive: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf, 'Cookie': session},
  })
}

(async () => {
  const pingRes = await ping()
  const loginRes = await login(extractTokens(pingRes))
  await getData(extractTokens(loginRes))
})()
```

Comment: I've been stuck with this for 2 days without being able to figure out what's wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.